# What is the difference between "s’interroger sur" and "se renseigner sur"?

Tags: sens

I think "se renseigner sur" is about trying to find out more information about a matter by asking around other people.

But what is the meaning of "s’interroger sur"? You just keep thinking about a matter by yourself in your head, even without consulting relevant files or looking it up on the web?

> - Il a été très troublé par cette nouvelle. **Il s’est interrogé sur** les liens entre les deux organisations.
> - Il a été très troublé par cette nouvelle. **Il s’est renseigné sur** les liens entre les deux organisations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*S'interroger* is more "philosophical". It's to wonder about something.

- Je *m'interroge* sur le sens de la vie.
- Je *m'interroge* sur ses capacités à passer son permis de conduire.
- Je *m'interroge* sur le temps qu'il va faire demain.
- Il *s'interroge*: A-t-il suffisamment d’œufs pour faire un gâteau demain?

*Se renseigner sur* is more about obtaining info about something. Generally pratical info.

- Je dois *me renseigner* sur les horaires de train, si je veux être à l'heure à la réunion.
- Il *se renseigne* sur les conditions de validation de son diplôme.
- Je *me suis renseignée* sur les films qui sortent en ce moment: J'ai demandé à un journaliste spécialisé dans le cinéma.

Mais aussi:

- Il *s'est renseigné*: Il n'y pas de train en direction de Paris.

Qu'on pourrait dire aussi:

- Il s'est renseigné **sur** les trains en direction de Paris.

M'interroger = myself to myself. Asking to myself. (and sometimes more "philosophical as it is to wonder)
Se renseigner = asking to someone else to get the info. (and more pratical)

Il s’est interrogé sur les liens entre les deux organisations. -> he wonders to himself.
Il s’est renseigné sur les liens entre les deux organisations. -> he asked someone.